# how do i sum all array arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a webpage with one input box and two button. first button for adding input box value to my array and the second to sum all array values. but it return 0 :(

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter number" id="input">
<button id="add">Add to Array</button>
<button id="sum">Sum All</button>
<p id="text"></p>
<script>
    var myArr = [];  //contain numbers that i've inputed
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
    var sumBtn = document.getElementById('sum');
    addBtn.onclick = function () {
            myArr.push(input.value);
            input.value = "";
        }
    function sumAll() {
        var i , sum = 0;
        for ( i in myArr.length ) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    sumBtn.onclick = function(){
        var paragraph = document.getElementById('text');
        var a = sumAll();
        paragraph.innerHTML = a;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Debug your code using a debugger.

Comment: it works @JaromandaX , but still have some problems to calculate..

Comment: @torazburo which debugger do you prefer ?

Comment: Your loop is not correct. `for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; ++i)` would be more logic. Or `for( i in myArr)` but you will need to do some filter

Comment: i have changed to this `for ( i in myArr )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the for-of syntax to loop thru your array.

```
function sumAll() {
    var i , sum = 0;
    for ( i of myArr ) {
        sum += Number(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your for loop properly:
When you say `for ( i in myArr.length ) {`the value of i comes out as undefined so the summation never happens. You should use debugging to figure out such issues.

```
function sumAll() {
            var i, sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < myArr.length;i++) {
                sum += +myArr[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Notice `+myArr[i];`that uses unary operator +. This can attempt to convert the string in the input field to number(both int and floats).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators

Answer (score -1):

This should be way to go.. 
1.You have to use parseInt to treat values as ints 
2.Loop correctly over array

```
<script>
        var myArr = [];  //contain numbers that i've inputed
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        var addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
        var sumBtn = document.getElementById('sum');
        addBtn.onclick = function () {
                myArr.push(input.value);
                input.value = "";
            }
        function sumAll() {
              var i , sum = 0;
            for ( i in myArr ) {
                sum += parseInt(myArr[i]);
            }
            return sum;
        }
        sumBtn.onclick = function(){
            var paragraph = document.getElementById('text');
            var a = sumAll();
            paragraph.innerHTML = a;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: why limit to integers? nothing in the question suggests the numbers are integers

Comment: in `for ( i in myArr )` , i takes the array index or array value ?

Comment: @Jaromanda X  The question clearly says sum ,and word "sum" always deals with numbers.. ,not sure about the reason of the downvote though

Comment: @Hirad ,its going to index

Comment: @manni `"sum" always deals with numbers` ... 3.14 is a number but `parseInt(3.14) === 3` so, your sum of 3.14 + 2.86 would produce 5, not 6

Comment: @Jaromanda X , the program OP had posted had syntactical issues in the way array is iterated in javascript. As long as its addressed these modifications can be done easily( to take care of other data types). The scope of the answer can be extended as maximum as possible .@Hirad ,did you find what you were looking for, if yes please mark whichever answer helped you.